# Python dictionary Bingo game. Need help checking for vertical win

Tags: python

I am writing a Bingo game as homework for class. I am super proud of it so far but it doesn't register some wins.

Here is the code that generates the card:

```py
def generate_card():
    card = {
        "B": [],
        "I": [],
        "N": [],
        "G": [],
        "O": [],
    }
    min = 1
    max = 15
    for letter in card:
        card[letter] = random.sample(range(min, max), 5)
        min += 15
        max += 15
        if letter == "N":
            card[letter][2] = "X" # free space!
    return card
```

and here is the method that checks for a win:

```py
def check_win(card):
    win = False
    if card["B"][0] == "X" and card["I"][1] == "X" and card["N"][2] == "X" and card["G"][3] == "X" and card["O"][4] == "X":
        win = True
    elif card["O"][0] == "X" and card["G"][1] == "X" and card["N"][2] == "X" and card["I"][3] == "X" and card["B"][4] == "X":
        win = True
    elif card["B"][0] == "X" and card["O"][4] == "X" and card["B"][4] == "X" and card["O"][0] == "X":
        win = True
    for letter in card:
        if(len(set(card[letter]))==1):
            win = True
    for letter in card:
        for number in letter:
            i = 0
            if card[letter][i] == "X":
                i += 1
        if i == 5:
            win == True
            break
    return win
```

It first checks for a diagonal win, then a four-corner win, then checks for a horizontal win, and, finally, a vertical win. I just tested and it looks like the code that checks for a vertical win isn't working. I am not sure why, but I do know it was hard trying to rack my brain to write the code for it. Any help is appreciated!

Also, if you see any other problems, let me know! I'm finding this super hard to test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There wasn't a logic error in my code, rather a simple syntax mistake on my part. In the if statement where it's checking if i is equal to 5, I had a conditional `win == True` and I should have been setting win equal to true: `win = True`

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this:

```
for i in range(5):
    cnt = 0
    for letter in card:
        if letter[i] == "X":
            cnt += 1
    if cnt == 5:
        win == True
        break
```

Comment: Thank you, but the error wasn't my code, it was a syntax mistake. It seems here you did that as well. It should have been `win = True` instead of `win == True` :)